# Contents of div is overflowing even when I specify maxWidth as 100%

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, overflow

I'm using React + Tailwind and rendering a component that renders list of buttons.

```
<div id="main" className="flex flex-col items-center md:flex-row max-w-full">
      <p className="text-lg whitespace-nowrap">{type}</p>
      <div id="wrapper" className="max-w-full overflow-x-auto">
        <div id="parent" className="flex" role="group">
          {data.map((item) => (
            <button
              key={item.id}
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-sm md:btn-md"
            >
              {item.name}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Since I was told that width and overflow properties don't work with flexbox, I created a wrapper div with id="wrapper" and put the flexbox div with id="parent" in it and applied the width and overflow properties on it. What I expect is that the "wrapper" div or "main" div must obey the max-w-full property and add a scrollbar when displaying the flexbox but it does not work as expected. But instead the flexbox div with id="wrapper" is overflowing. Please help me understand what am I doing wrong here.